# How to import module.exports => params in 'srcds-rcon'

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, rcon

I don't can import npm package in my folder project.
Docs say
`

```
let Rcon = require('srcds-rcon');
let rcon = Rcon({
    address: '192.168.1.10',
    password: 'test'
});
```

Docs link - https://www.npmjs.com/package/srcds-rcon/v/2.2.0
I can't import this package in any way to use Rcon
I tried

```
import Rcon from 'srcds-rcon'

import { Rcon } from 'srcds-rcon'

import * as Rcon from 'srcds-rcon'
```

My tsconfig.json

```
"target": "ES2016",
"module": "commonjs",
```

Editor: vs code,
Package manager: npm

Comment: tell us your editor and package manager

Comment: How are you executing your typescript? How do you transpile it, how do you bundle it, where do you run it?